# Validating an error on a property in grails

Tags: java, grails

Basically what do you put in the `if`s so that it filters if there's an error in one of the properties.

Lets say i have three properties in the MyClass domain. Then when one errors, the if for that property will trigger

```
def save(Long id){
    def myInstance = new MyClass(params)

    if (!myInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        if(){
        //show my custom error message 1
        redirect(action: "list")
        return 
        }
        if(){
        //show my custom error message 2
        redirect(action: "list")
        return 
        }
        if(){ 
        //show my custom error message 3
        redirect(action: "list") 
        return
        }
    } 

    //show my created message
    redirect(action: "list")       
}
```

Comment: myInstance.errors.allErrors.each {} ?

Comment: @baxxabit but this would just iterate all errors. i still cant identify what field so the custom errors would not be right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  hasFieldErrors(String field) function:

```
if(myInstance.errors.hasFieldErrors('myField')) {
    //...
}
```